# PLINQ on ConcurrentQueue isn't multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, postgresql, plinq, npgsql

I have the following PLINQ statement in a C# program:

```
 foreach (ArrestRecord arrest in
            from row in arrestQueue.AsParallel()
            select row)
        {
            Geocoder geocodeThis = new Geocoder(arrest);
            writeQueue.Enqueue(geocodeThis.Geocode());
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Enqueued " + ++k);
        }
```

Both `arrestQueue` and `writeQueue` are [ConcurrentQueues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Nothing is running in parallel:

- While running, total CPU usage is about 30%, and this is with everything else running, too. I have 8 cores (Hyper-Threading on a Core i7 720QM with 4 physical cores), and 4 of the 8 cores have virtually no utilization at all. The rest run roughly 40%-50%.
- Disk usage is usually 0%, and there's no network usage except for queries to a Postgres DB on localhost (see below).
- If I add a breakpoint somewhere inside `geocodeThis.Geocode()`, Visual Studio's **Thread** dropdown just says **[*pid*] Main Thread**. It never goes to any other thread.
- I am using [Npgsql](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/npgsql/) to connect to Postgres, and each thread runs a few **SELECT** queries against a table. I am running pgAdmin III's Server Status app, which shows **pg_stat_activity**. Through monitoring this, and strategic breakpoint placement (see above), I can see that the app *never* has more than 1 database connection open for all supposedly concurrent threads running `geocodeThis.Geocode()`. Even if I add **Pooling=false** to the DB connection string, to force connections not to be pooled, I never see more than 1 connection used in `geocodeThis.Geocode()`.
- The Postgres table is indexed on every column in the **WHERE** clause. Even if it was poorly indexed, I'd expect lots of disk usage. If Postgres was holding things up in any other way, seems like it would soak a core.

This seems like a simple PLINQ case study, and I am scratching my head as to why nothing's running in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are parallelizing just the enumeration of the `assertQueue` itself and then "unparallelizing" it back into an ordinary `IEnumerable`.  This all happens before the `foreach` loop even starts.  Then you use the ordinary `IEnumerable` with the `foreach` which runs the body of the loop serially.

There are many ways to run the body of the loop in parallel but the first one that comes to mind is using `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.ForEach(arrestQueue, arrest =>
    {
        Geocoder geocodeThis = new Geocoder(arrest);
        writeQueue.Enqueue(geocodeThis.Geocode());
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Enqueued " + ++k);
    });
```

Comment: There's a second enumeration in there- I missed it the first time too.  But after adding that this works too.

Comment: @Chris: `arrestQueue` is of type `ConcurrentQueue<ArrestRecord>` record.  Try to compile your (edited) code and the original poster's code with dummy types.

Comment: Ack, you are right!  Read that as a second enumeration.  Edited accordingly.

Comment: @Chris: It is an enumeration.  It just an enumeration of the `foreach (var item in input) yield return item;` variety.  :-)

Comment: Thanks!! That worked, but I am confused: how am I unparallelizing in the original PLINQ?

I see you're using the Task Parallel Library instead of PLINQ...

Comment: @Aren: You are unparallelizing by using `foreach`, which only accepts an `IEnumerable`. To put it another way, you **were** performing the query in parallel, but not the **body**. `ForEach` from the TPL is a good choice because it allows finer control over the loop.  You can set the degree of parallelism etc.  PLINQ works too but isn't as flexible.  Just not `foreach`!

Answer (score 1):

Foreach over a parallel collection is still a single threaded operation.  .AsParallel returns a collection which defines a .ForAll method, which may (but by contract will not always) run in parallel. The code for that would be:

```
arrestQueue.AsParallel().ForAll(arrest=>
    {
        Geocoder geocodeThis = new Geocoder(arrest);
        writeQueue.Enqueue(geocodeThis.Geocode());
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Enqueued " + ++k);
    });
```